# hdfs fsck Permission denied

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fsck

I'm running this command line to resolve the problem of corrupt HDFS FIles :

```
hdfs fsck /
```

And I get this warning :

```
Connecting to namenode via http://master1:50070
FSCK started by root (auth:SIMPLE) from /192.168.1.30 for path / at Mon Oct 24 05:06:23 EDT 2016
FSCK ended at Mon Oct 24 05:06:23 EDT 2016 in 1 milliseconds
Permission denied: user=root, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/accumulo":accumulo:accumulo:drwxr-x--x
```

Any help please !!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot execute `fsck` with normal user. You should run it with `hdfs` as superuser

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs fsck /
```

In the case of only `accumulo`, you can try below

```
sudo -u accumulo hdfs fsck /accumulo
```

Answer (score 1):

You should run this command as an "hdfs" user:

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs fsck /
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a permission issue.

Run this command from hadoop bin and then try again.

```
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /accumulo
```

To disable permission check, set the below property in hdfs-site.xml and restart your cluster

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
```

Comment: IT dosen't work, but when I do : `sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /accumulo` it work fine. But when I do this I have another permission denied on another inode.